# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row into my Database

Tags: php, pdo, insert, key

i got a Problem with inserting a child row into my Database. Ill always get the Error Insert Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`doku`.`server`, CONSTRAINT `kunde->server` FOREIGN KEY (`kunden_id`) REFERENCES `kunden` (`id`))

The Code is

```
<form method="POST" action="server-eintragen.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firmenname">Servername</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Servername" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Addresse">Bestückung</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CPU" placeholder="Welche CPU?" >
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CPU-Anzahl" placeholder="Wieviele Sockets?" >
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="RAM" placeholder="Wieviel RAM" >
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Festplatte" placeholder="Wie groß ist die Festplatte" >
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="kunden_id" value=<?php htmlentities($_GET['kundenid']) ?> >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Abschicken</button>
                </div>
          </form>
```

and

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);

include "../../includes/php/db.php";
$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$cpu = htmlentities($_POST['CPU']);
$cpu_anzahl = htmlentities($_POST['CPU-Anzahl']);
$ram= htmlentities($_POST['RAM']);
$festplatte = htmlentities($_POST['Festplatte']);
$created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$kunden_id = htmlentities($_POST['kundenid']);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO server (name, cpu, cpu_anzahl, ram, festplatte, created_at, updated_at, kunden_id)VALUES( :name, :cpu, :cpu_anzahl, :ram, :festplatte, :created_at, :updated_at, :kunden_id)');

try {
    $stmt->execute(
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'cpu' => $cpu,
            'cpu_anzahl' => $cpu_anzahl,
            'ram' => $ram,
            'festplatte' => $festplatte,
            'created_at' => $created_at,
            'updated_at' => $updated_at,
            'kunden_id' => $kunden_id
        )
    );
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo 'Insert Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

My Databasedesign is like that:http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4698/vczudxas_jpg.htm

Comment: So what's the value of `$kunden_id` and does it exist in the database?

Comment: i think you are getting an id in $kunden_id  variable  which is not available in parent table(kunden).kindly print the variable to see its value

Comment: $kunden_id is in my test case 3 and this is the id of the kunde (customer) in my database. and yeah the echo is also "3" so it should exist in my database but in the colum of customer[id] in the server colum it doenst exist i wanna insert it with the new server data

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4698/3tidwhvz_jpg.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quotes "" around the hidden field's value, if you add them, it's not null and everything should work fine.

Also you should check for emptiness of the parameter, and you should also check whether the kunde with kunden_id exists, because the POST-parameters could be manipulated and a kunde gets updated which the user does not have the right for.

Additionally, you only need htmlentities for outputting, if you insert with entities and you output with entities, it is wrong, as you can see here: https://3v4l.org/5dNGO

Tip: Use an IDE like eclipse, or PHPStorm if you can afford, then you see it at first glance. Just look at your code in the question.

Comment: thanks. If i wanna insert multiple rows into my database with the some foreign key (kunden_id) how do i do that cause it has to be unique or an index? Like i wanna have 3 Servers for one Customer but still linked to the Customer ID

Comment: If it works, could you then please accept the answer? :D It has to be an index, not unique, like that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/629366/2

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

When two tables are binded with `foreign key` relation say

```
tbl_parent(id) -> tbl_child(cid);  // here cid refers to id
```

then in `cid` column, you can only insert those values which are already present in `id` column.

And in your case, I think you are trying to insert a value in child table which are not present in parent.

So as per your last comment `$kunden_id` is blank there, so I can't be inserted as blank is not present in parent table (**as parent table reference columns is an unique or primary key column**)

Comment: Yeah but in my id colum there is the value "3" which equals to my insert... http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4698/3tidwhvz_jpg.htm

Comment: Echo the prepared and query and run it on mysql terminal and see what happens

Comment: Manually its working. So there must be some error somewhere in my code.

Comment: The error is showing for the same query in the above posted code ?

Comment: No. I tried INSERT INTO server (name, cpu, cpu_anzahl, ram, festplatte, created_at, updated_at, kunden_id)VALUES( 'test', 'test', '1', '1', '1', 'a timestamp', 'timestamp', '3') and thats working. so its not the query it must be something in the handover

Comment: Ok im getting closer. I cant echo the $kunden_id in my server-eintragen.php

Comment: Now its just the question why its not sending over the information... in the form i can echo it in my insert file its not ( i can echo $_GET['kundenid'] but i cant access it via $kunden_id = $_POST['kunden_id'];